# Lint check to detect Implicit Internal Intent vulnerability

Tags: android, checkstyle, android-security, android-lint, spotbugs

We got an error in Play Store Console about our app having an "Implicit Internal Intent" vulnerability ([error info](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10399926)). The error is fixed, however we would like to add a way to detect these vulnerabilities sooner.

Is there any Android Lint Check or any other library that can detect these vulnerabilities?

Thanks